# get wordpress post content in google map infowindow with table shortcode

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, google-maps, infowindow

I'd like to display inside a google maps infowindow a page content, and it works as long as there's only text before the  tag. But I'd like to include a table generated by a shortcode from the plugin "inline google spreadsheet viewer" (https://wordpress.org/plugins/inline-google-spreadsheet-viewer/). When I write the shortcode before the  tag, the map is broken (the marker doesn't show).

Here is the code

```
                                $locations = array();
                                $this_page_id=$wp_query->post->ID;
                                $location_query = new WP_Query( array(
                                    'showposts' => 20,
                                    'post_parent' => $this_page_id,
                                    'post_type' => 'page'
                                 ) );
                                echo "//markers: 10\n";
                                $comma = "";
                                while ( $location_query->have_posts() ) {
                                    $location_query->the_post();
                                    $title = str_replace("'", "\'", get_the_title());
                                    $permalink = get_permalink();
                                    $content = get_the_content();
                                    $content = apply_filters( 'the_content', $content );
                                    $latitude = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'latitude', true );
                                    $longitude = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'longitude', true );
                                    $locations[]=array(the_title('<h4>','</h4>',false).
                                         '<div id="'.$post->ID.'">'.$post->post_content.'</div><br/><a href="$permalink" class="button">Voir la station</a>',
                                       $latitude,
                                       $longitude,
                                       $NUM++
                                       ); 
                                echo "\nvar locations=".json_encode($locations).";\n";
```

I can see the content in the infowindow but the table doesn't display, only the shortcode text. How can I filter the content to get it to display the table into the infowindow ?

Thanks !

Comment: Seems you use `get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'latitude', true ),` twice in your second code. You might change one of the lines to `get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'longitude', true ),`

Comment: I edited the code but I still can't get the table to display... only the shortcode text !